# How to set default value of UITypeEditor

Tags: uitypeeditor

I have this property of a custom object to be displayed in a PropertyGrid:

```
    [DisplayName("Dirección IP Local")]
    [Editor(typeof(Configuracion.Editors.IPAddressEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [Description("Dirección IP del computador en el cual está conectado el dispositivo.")]
    public IPAddress IPLocal { get; set; }
```

In constructor of the same class I have:

```
this.IPLocal = Common.Helper.ProgramInfo.GetLocalIPAddresses().FirstOrDefault();
```

The IPAddressEditor is this:

```
public class IPAddressEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    private IWindowsFormsEditorService _editorService;
    private IpAddressInput _ipAddressInput;
    private bool _escKeyPressed;

    public IPAddressEditor()
    {
        _ipAddressInput = new IpAddressInput();
        _ipAddressInput.Width = 150;
        _ipAddressInput.BackgroundStyle.BorderWidth = -1;
        _ipAddressInput.ButtonClear.Visible = true;
        _ipAddressInput.ValueChanged += _ipAddressInput_ValueChanged;
        _ipAddressInput.PreviewKeyDown += _ipAddressInput_PreviewKeyDown;
    }

    void _ipAddressInput_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            _escKeyPressed = true;
    }

    void _ipAddressInput_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_editorService != null)
            _editorService.CloseDropDown();
    }

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }

    public override object EditValue(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        if (provider != null)
        {
            _editorService =
                provider.GetService(
                typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService))
                as IWindowsFormsEditorService;
        }

        if (_editorService != null)
        {
            _escKeyPressed = false;

            _editorService.DropDownControl(_ipAddressInput);

            if (!_escKeyPressed)
            {
                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.None;
                if (IPAddress.TryParse(_ipAddressInput.Value, out ip))
                    return ip;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the control inside the editor (in this case _ipAddressInput) is not initialized with the value I assigned in object constructor.

This is obvious because in type editor constructor I am creating a new instance of IpAddressInput, so the question is: what is the best way to initialize it?

I was thinking about creating a public setter for that variable and calling in constructor of the custom object using a TypeDescriptor, but I think this is tricky,

Is there a better solution?

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the solution.

I just added

```
_ipAddressInput.Text = value.ToString();
```

before the call to

```
_editorService.DropDownControl(_ipAddressInput);
```

I have thought about it before but I underestimate it because I was wondering what will happen when updating the property using the editor and whether it will keep the modified value.It was no problem with that and the editor worked like a charm.